# Parcelable: Creating an instance of creator and implementing methods inline - CREATOR is an interface?

Tags: java, android

I have just been creating a `Parcelable` and I had to create a `CREATOR` field inside the `Parcelable` and implement 2 methods. The problem is that `CREATOR` actually implements an interface of `Parcelable.Creator`. What I don't understand is how it is possible to create an instance of a interface.

Normally I thought it we would use the word "implements" on my custom class.

I am coming from .NET so that's probably why it seems a little strange. Here is an example.:

```
 public static final Parcelable.Creator<Account> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Account>() {
    public Account createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Account(in);
    }

    public Account[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Account[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: An instance of any class that implements an interface is (loosely speaking) an instance of that interface.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating an instance of an interface like this is called declaring an anonymous class.

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Account> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Account>() {
    public Account createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Account(in);
    }

    public Account[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Account[size];
    }
};
```

It is equivalent to implementing the interface normally like this:

```
private static class ExampleCreator implements Parcelable.Creator<Account> {

    public Account createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Account(in);
    }

    public Account[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Account[size];
    }
}
```

And then creating a public static field like this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Account> CREATOR = new ExampleCreator();
```

But instead of explicitly implementing the interface in a named class you are implementing the interface implicitly without giving the resulting class a name which is why it's called an anonymous class!

---

Doing something like this is pretty common in Java and it happens all the time wether people know it or not. For example you can do the same thing with an abstract class:

```
public static abstract class SomeAbstractClass {

    public abstract void fooTheBar();

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Something happened!");
    }
}

public SomeAbstractClass someInstance = new SomeAbstractClass() {
    @Override
    public void fooTheBar() {
        System.out.println("The bar is fooed!");
    }
};
```

Here the type of the field `someInstance` is not actually `SomeAbstractClass` but another anonymous class which extends `SomeAbstractClass` but additionally implements `fooTheBar()`.

---

The reason why you have to specifically create this anonymous class of `Parcelable.Creator` as a public static field is simply convention. Every `Parcelable` has to define a constant field which implements `Parcelable.Creator`. The framework looks for this field at runtime and uses it to create instances of that particular `Parcelable`.

Comment: Thanks Xaver, now it makes sense